# How repeating differents lines at different times in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, transform, ubuntu-16.04, bigdata

How I can repeat different lines at different times, using a file with specification? (I think that will be better exemplify)

Example (file that I want repeated lines):

```
ID01 rs01 AB
ID02 rs01 BA
OA03 rs01 AA
EA04 rs01 BB
```

Example (**file specifying how many times each line must have repeated**- specifying the character in first column):

```
ID01 1
ID02 5
OA03 2
EA04 3
```

And I want the **output file**:

```
ID01 rs01 AB
ID02 rs01 BA
ID02 rs01 BA
ID02 rs01 BA
ID02 rs01 BA
ID02 rs01 BA
OA03 rs01 AA
OA03 rs01 AA
EA04 rs01 BB
EA04 rs01 BB
EA04 rs01 BB
```

But in my case, my real data is big. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following python script will do the job:

```
import sys

default_repeats = 1

repeats_file = open(sys.argv[2])
data_file = open(sys.argv[1])

repeats = { i: int(n) for i, n in ( l.split()[:2] for l in  repeats_file.readlines() ) }

for line in data_file.readlines():
    identifier = line.split(' ')[0]
    sys.stdout.write(line * repeats.get(identifier, default_repeats))
```

It accepts two arguments:

```
$ python script_file.py <file_with_data> <file_with_repetitions>
```

Comment: Thank you. But appear an error that I did not find the solution:    `Traceback (most recent call last): File " script_file.py", line 10, in <module> print line * repeats[identifier], keyError: '1' `. How I can resolve this? Thank you verry much.

Comment: This error occurs when particular id is not included inside file with repetitions. I've edited this script and currently in such situation it will repeat line using default number of repetitions specified in `default_repeats` variable.

Comment: But I have the file with repetitions, and I used the first column of this file to created my data. So, I think that `file with data` have all id. No? What do you think?

Comment: `file_with_data` should contain data in format specified in your first example, and `file_with_repetitions` should contain data in format from second example.

Comment: Thank you @qzb. It did run.

Comment: I am sorry discommode again. But in my real data (that the numbers of line is bigger than examplo - how I said) apper the following error:`File "script_file.py", line 8, in <module> ... line 8, in <dictcomp> ... ValueError: too many values to unpack`. My data format is equal of example. What I can do? Thank you.

Comment: One of rows inside `file_with_repetitions` contains more than 2 words. I've edited answer again, but I'm not sure if it will work, because I don't know your real data.